# why do my par 16 halogen lighbulbs keep exploding?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have recessed ceiling lights that are rated to 75W.  I use par 16 halogen reflector lightbulbs (sylvania brand), which are what was being used when i moved in.  In the past 15 months, 6 different bulbs have failed.   Two times, the actual filament casing exploded.  Also, four different lighbulbs have failed in the past 15 months.  The metal flange that holds the glass in place  falls off, and the glass then falls off, shattering on the floor.

I called sylvania and they said there have been no reported problems with their bulbs.

Comment: Are you saying that 6 PAR16 lights and 4 **other** lights have failed? Sounds like nothing to do with the PAR16's and probably a voltage issue in your house.

Comment: Are you sure it's rated to 75W with a 16 PAR? I just looked a can I have laying around; 16 par is NOT listed at ANY wattage.

Comment: @mazura, i am sure that the fixtures are rates to 75W.

Comment: @Doxylover, all of the issues are with par16 bulbs, and none of my other fixtures have issues, so i think it is related to the bulbs.

Comment: I spoke with Sylvania this week and their consumer safety dept called me - they said in veryu genreal terms that there have been some reported problems and that they have redesigned the bulb to address those issues.

Comment: D you should type this up as an answer and accept it it would possibly help others I just happens across it.